# How to install Gnomeradio in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

How to install Gnomeradio in Ubuntu 16.04?

Thanks.

Comment: Installing through the software center or `sudo apt-get install gnomeradio` doesn't work?

Comment: No, I have tried to do this and I couldn´t

Comment: @MiJyn it is not is Ubuntu  repositories now!!